# No suitable driver found for jdbc embedded derby database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I have made an app with netbeans using embedded derby database. The app work well when I run it in netbeans but I made clean and build jar file it make error saying

> "No suitable driver found jdbc:derby:database;create = true"

that is how i connect to database

```
String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:booksdb;create=true";
 
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
```